# What is the difference between a Rule and a Policy

Tags: database, rules, policy, rule, policies

in the context of a database, we sometimes need to check values against some statements like **"the customer name is non-empty"** or **"the customer number of purchases is positive"**...

But do such statements constitute rules or policies ?

**In general how would you define these concepts, their differences and relations ?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a question about the English language? This doesn't seem to be programming related, so can you please try and make it so?

Comment: @Oded: it's about the semantics of these terms in the context of a database management. It will help me name some types, so yes the final purpose is programming.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you're talking about; I've run into such distinctions before (even though the English words are not all that different) and here is how I think it plays out in most business computing areas.

A rule in such a context is something that--whether it's a structural fact or a business-imposed statement--will not change, or at least stands only a very small chance of changing.  Most statements of the form "X cannot be null" represent rules.  "Null" typically doesn't make much sense to a business user; usually you arrive at these rules by examining the way that your model is constructed.  A change to a rule has far-reaching consequences to the way that your database and any supporting applications are built.

A policy is more like a business instruction.  Preferred customers get 10% off may be a policy, but as you know, things like this tend to change.  A change to a policy may impact the way your application works, but not its fundamental architecture or underpinnings.

Pragmatically speaking--and it sounds like you may already know this--you want to make policies relatively easy to change.  Rules, while they may change, are typically more involved: changing a rule often requires changing code, UIs, mental models, ways of thought, and so on.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of a database, I would argue that it's a rule to have a username, while it's a policy (potentially overridden by administrative or other approval) to allow customers to have a lower assigned discount if they have less than a set number of purchases.

```
Rule: All users must have a username.
Rule: All users must have a password.
Rule: All users must have a valid email address.
Rule: All users must have a valid credit card on file.
Policy: All users begin with a 0% discount rate on purchases.
Policy: All users are required to pay for shipping.
```

Rules are outward-facing statements backed by validation. Policies are internal rules backed by consequence.

It could be a policy that later on down the road, a user can change a username (depending on how the software was written), or that the discount and shipping rates assigned on signup may be adjusted to create customer opportunities.

In my estimation then, a rule requires hard validation, while a policy by nature is subject to intervention and/or manipulation.

HTH

Jared

Comment: thanks, your opinion seems really similar to the one of Laird.

Comment: @Serious: I would think we are saying the same thing, I just wanted to illustrate it in a different way.

Comment: @Serious: I'd also like to suggest that rules can belong to policies (if a user is active and has a suitable activity ranking [rule-defined attributes], allow to post comments but not edit entries), but policies I would not think be part of a rule.

Comment: thanks, indeed your point makes sense.